# Magento 2 add new block template file

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, phtml, parent-child-theme

I am trying to add a new **phtml** template file (**in my child theme**) of a **custom module** (not mine).

**Here is the block :**

```
{{block class="Sm\FilterProducts\Block\FilterProducts" template="Sm_FilterProducts::default-grid-column-id16.phtml" title_module="New product"  product_source="news_products" product_limitation="8"}}
```

I changed the template to: `Magento_Theme::mytemplate.phtml` without success.

**Edit for more information :**

I have created a `mytemplate.phtml` in the folder app of my theme :

```
app/design/frontend/hexa/Ztheme/template/page/html/sm_template.phtml
```

Comment: Cleared block_html and full_page caches?

Comment: I still have  Invalid template file: 'Magento_Theme::sm_template.phtml' in module: 'Sm_FilterProducts' block's name: 'filterproducts_0'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app/design/frontend/hexa/Ztheme/Magento_Theme/templates/page/html/sm_template.phtml
```

for

```
Magento_Theme::page/html/mytemplate.phtml
```

and For

```
 Sm_FilterProducts::default-grid-column-id16.phtml
```

you must create an file in this folder

```
app/design/frontend/hexa/Ztheme/Sm_FilterProducts/templates/default-grid-column-id16.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks you. I was not using the right directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try

> Magento_Theme::html/sm_template.phtml

in your block template.

Hope it helps!!